# How can I remove resources from a CfnInclude imported CloudFormation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm importing an existing Cloudformation stack into CDK using the method described in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/use_cfn_template.html).

The imported stack contains resources which I want to remove from AWS, so I'm looking for some delete/remove method in the imported cfnInclude:

```js
    const cfnInclude = new cfn_inc.CfnInclude(this, 'Template', { 
      templateFile: 'ExistingTemplate.json'
    });
    // I'm looking for a method like this:
    // cfnInclude.remove('MyResourceName');
```

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `tryRemoveChild` on the underlying [Node](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/constructs.Node.html#class-node) to remove a child construct by name.

```js
const success = cfnInclude.node.tryRemoveChild('MyFunctionToRemove');  // returns boolean
```

Note this is [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) functionality available to all Construct subclasses, not anything specific to `CfnInclude.`

Comment: Thanks. I like a simple answer. This does indeed give me what I needed.

Comment: One concern - I note that the tryRemoveChild method is marked 'This API element is experimental. It may change without notice'. I guess I cross my fingers it won't change anytime soon. (ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/constructs.Node.html#trywbrremovewbrchildchildnamespan-classapi-icon-api-icon-experimental-titlethis-api-element-is-experimental-it-may-change-without-noticespan)

Comment: @Elliveny  If `tryRemoveChild` were to disappear, the workaround in your case would be to use javascript to remove unwanted resources from the template _before_ importing.  `JSON.parse`, `delete` unwanted resource keys, `JSON.stringify`, import.

Comment: Yup, interesting. To take that approach further I could just edit the template json I suppose!